# UnitTesting in VS2010: How to ship unit tests and test runner in the executable?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

i want to ship unit test code, and the test runner, in the final executable that is given to the customer.

> i [want to do this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0490084/) so that tests can be run at, by, for or with the customer.

The problem is that Visual Studio's test system seems to be contained in the assembly:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

and this assembly doesn't ship with the .NET framework (full or client profile).

This would mean that i would not be able to run the tests on a machine that does not have Visual Studio (2010) installed.

What's the next best workaround, given the requirement of a single executable.

---

It's quite handy [in other languages](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/) to be able to access unit tests with an advanced keyboard shortcut:

[image]

This way i can run my unit tests, my functional tests, and my integration tests at the customer site, or to aid problem solving.

Not that i need to justify my question.

Comment: I've never heard of customers running unit tests.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Some entities have entire groups dedicated to testing

Comment: What's that have to do with unit tests?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Testers in the testing group run tests.

Comment: Yeah, but unit tests are meant to be very small and very narrow. They're not the sort of thing that QA normally does in most shops.

Comment: @JohnSaunders i like the quote, "Just because a test's written in NUnit, doesn't make it a unit test."

Answer (score 1):

The [proposed workaround by Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/413704/please-include-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-unittestframework-dll-in-the-net-framework) is to use .Net 4's [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)

So far, I have only heard success [Shipping unit tests using NUnit](http://notgartner.wordpress.com/2006/02/16/shipping-unit-tests-with-application-code/). Can you use NUnit?

Comment: i suppose i'd have to use NUnit, since there is no solution. Problem with that is that i'd have to get NUnit, then find a test runner, then find an IDE extension that can add tests.

Comment: I'm really missing something here. Why do you need an IDE extension to add tests. It's not difficult to add them by hand. Why do you need to find a test runner? NUnit comes with one.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's actually very tedious to add them by hand. It requires creating a new unit, adding methods, and tagging them with test attributes. i did't realize NUnit came with a runner; based on all the questions i've read over the years asking for test runners.

Comment: I've just never used an IDE to create unit tests. Just curious.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's like programming with code insight or code completion. And now i see why i can't find a test runner with NUnit installed: i cannot find a test runner with NUnit installed!

Comment: i also can't figure out how to add NUnit to my solution - so many hard-coded paths in various config files. Might have to end up writing my own test framework (*sigh*)