# Web-based NUnit test runner for ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, nunit, test-runner

Is there any web-based test runner; to run a web-site's unit tests from the web-site?

---

i know this is runs afoul of some people's dogma, but i want to be able to [run unit tests from inside the product i'm testing](http://notgartner.wordpress.com/2006/02/16/shipping-unit-tests-with-application-code/). Whether this be from inside [the native Win32 executable](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/), or from within [a .NET executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017995/unittesting-in-vs2010-how-to-ship-unit-tests-and-test-runner-in-the-executable).

A guy has already written [a web-based AJAX test runner](http://syncor.blogspot.ca/2010/02/adding-graphical-test-runner-for.html) for [UnitTest++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unittest-cpp/).

In the past i had to rip apart NUnit, so i could tests embedded in the executable without having to ship NUnit dlls. This required me to also write my own graphical test-runner for Windows/WinForms.

Has anyone already done the work of creating runnable unit-tests for ASP.net?

---

**Note**: The usual response by people: *"Unit tests are not supposed to be in the final product, and definitely not accessible by testers, support, or developers, when on-site."*

---

**Note**: You may disagree with my desire to run unit tests, but don't let that affect your answer. If there is no web-based nunit test runner for ASP.net then that's the answer. Don't be afraid to **answer the question**. i won't bite.

Comment: Could you post the reason why you want to do this.

Comment: @Jupaol So that i can run unit tests without having run switch Visual Studio to a different project. So i can run unit tests without having to be inside Visual Studio. So i can run unit tests after installation on the customer's test system. So i can run unit tests after installation on the customer's live system.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reasons why you want to do this kind of thing is because of the lack of a [Continuous Integration server](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html), I cannot think another justification, so instead of trying to *patch your design* by doing this, it would be cleaner if you evaluate the implementation of a CI server (which it's not so difficult, for instance you could look at: [NCastor](https://github.com/jupaol/NCastor))

So in my opinion what you need is to setup a continuous integration server in order to run unit tests and integration tests automatically as part of your automated build process.

You would be deploying your application to the next 'stage' **only** when the build process and the tests are valid, you can also configure the CI server to perform:

- run tests
- run static analysis
- run non-static analysis
- generate tests-reports
- run tests with test coverage
- calculate and set application version
- create packages of your application
- modify config files according to the target stage
- minify your scripts
- send emails when a build fails

Among others

And as you mentioned, you wouldn't need to deploy the tests to your production servers

I strongly recommend you to read the next article:

http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/16/top-10-things-i-do-on-every-project/

And this is a list of some CI servers

- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) - Free & Easy configuration
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) - Free & Easy configuration
- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) - Free for Open Source projects
- [Cruise Control](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) - Free (however, this has decreased in popularity because configuration is only available through XML files, it's annoying...)

Answer (score 1):

Found **NUnitWebRunner** on github https://github.com/tonyx/NUnitWebRunner